how to create multising account using polkadot extrinsics?
I have been working with multsig wallets i am able to create account using polkadot ui and use it to sign transaction, but  i am not able to create account using extrinsics can you please tell  how to  create multsig account  using polkadot extrinsics and  how to do transaction with it .

No multisig instance exists.
The equation f(accounts, threshold) = multisig determines a multisig address.
This calculation is performed in real time during use.
The chain does not require storage of any multisig data. Using consistent accounts and thresholds always yields the same fixed address. These accounts can also be computed off-chain.
If you're asking how to retain this address on the blockchain, simply send some funds to the keep the account data under this address.
